# How to invoke JsonSerializer inside another custom JsonSerializer Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have two classes. First with field of second class.

```
class A {
  @JsonSerializer(using = CustomBSerializer.class)
  private B b;
}

class B {
  ...
}
```

And I have two custom serializers:

```
class CustomBSerializer extends JsonSerializer<B> {
  ...
}

class CustomASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(A a, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        //write here
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

What method I should add instead of comment in `CustomASerializer` to write serialized value of field `b` with `CustomBSerializer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`writeObjectField`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#writeObjectField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method. `Jackson` should use default or custom serializer if exists.

Below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        B b = new B();
        b.setProperty("Value");

        A a = new A();
        a.setB(b);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(a));
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = ASerializer.class)
class A {

    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class ASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("now", new Date().toString());
        gen.writeObjectField("b", value.getB());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = BSerializer.class)
class B {

    private String property;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}

class BSerializer extends JsonSerializer<B> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(B value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("p", value.getProperty());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

prints:

```
{
  "now" : "Wed Aug 26 22:27:08 CEST 2015",
  "b" : {
    "p" : "Value"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it's not using my custom JsonSerializer.

Comment: How have you registered custom serializer for A class?

Comment: Try to put `JsonSerialize ` annotation on class level not on property level.

Comment: Yes I did the same and it works, but can I do it with annotation on property level?

Comment: You are writing custom serializer for a class which also has custom serializer. Maybe the fastest way to do this is creating new custom serializer and using it:
`gen.writeFieldName("b"); BSerializer bSerializer = new BSerializer();
        bSerializer.serialize(value.getB(), gen, serializers);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't always have access to class code, you will not always have the possibility to modify A or B class to put the annotation @JsonSerialize(using = BSerializer.class). In these cases you will need to call CustomBSerializer in CustomASerializer, which was also what the question was asking in first place. This is the way to do it:

```
class CustomASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(A a, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper)jgen.getCodec();
        SimpleModule module =  new SimpleModule("CustomBSerializer");
        module.addSerializer(B.class, new CustomBSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        mapper.writeValue(jgen, a.getB());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```